# How to use Facebook Authentication in ASP.NET Web Api MVC 6?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, facebook-authentication

I found these:

[First Web API](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html)

[Facebook on a WebApp](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/sociallogins.html)

I'm trying to apply the knowledge from the above samples into a Web API of my own.

My clients will be Android and IOS native apps.

The clients already use the Facebook sdk to request the token.

But how can i use this token to authenticate my user?

I would love some example.

PS.: I use DNX Core dnxcore50 as framework.

EDIT:

I manage to use Facebook Authentication using the following: [aspnet/Security/samples/SocialSample/Startup.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/samples/SocialSample/Startup.cs)

But the Response is a HTML to Facebook... I don't think that's how the WebAPI should bahave...

I think my question will be on this: [Creating Backend Services for Native Mobile Applications](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mobile/native-mobile-backend.html)